# Batching streams in RxJS that involve asynchronous steps

Tags: javascript, rxjs, stream-processing

I am processing a stream of data pulled, usually, from a `RxNode.fromReadableStream()` where there is an intermediate step that is asynchronous and may only run with a certain concurrency, and at the same time the output step can only run in serial, in discrete batches.

Basically a classic transformation pipeline:

```
cat file | parallel -P5 transform | xargs -n1000 process
```

With promises it would be something like (extremely simplified):

```js
lines.on('readable', function read() {
  let line;
  while (line = lines.read()) {
    queue.push(line);
    if (queue.length >= 10) {
      return Promise.map(queue, item => someAsyncTransformations(item), {concurrency: 5})
        .then(items => someFinalAsyncProcessing(items))
        .then(read);
    }
  }
});
```

By inserting the controller after the transforms, I can ensure that the transforms execute independently, giving me pipelining; and the combination of defers and merging seems to let me control asynchronicity and concurrency.

However, I'm using `controlled()` to make sure the map step effectively pauses processing until done. It looks really ugly — isn't there a better, non-manual way to implement lossless backpressure?

Also, I believe I have to use the same control trick with the transformers, otherwise the entire stream will be transformed in one go and blow memory usage. Is there a more idiomatic way?

Finally: The above actually doesn't work if the size of the input isn't divisible by the batch size. For some reason if I do `request()` with more than the number of the remaining items, the entire pipeline just quits; `onComplete` isn't even called. Actaully, if I initally call `request()` with a large number, the entire pipeline repeats seemingly indefinitely with the same contents. Bug or intended behaviour?

**Edit**: <s>I found I could use `concatMap`</s>. Nevermind.

Comment: Is `Rx.Observable.fromPromise(transform)` a typo? Also `defer` will accept a `Promise` you don't have to explicitly convert using `fromPromise`

Comment: Should have been `fromPromise(transform(item))`. Corrected now. I discovered that `defer` will accept a promise, thanks.

Comment: Also looking at the latest version on cdnjs it does appear to have bugs that are causing at least some of your woes, could you try it with the bleeding edge from github?

Comment: You're right, current master (which is going to be 3.0, apparently) fixes the request bug I encountered. Thanks!